# Getting Oracle stored procedure parameters

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a query in a SQL Server database that gets stored procedures parameters like this:

```
SELECT
    parameter.name, 
    types.name,
    types.is_nullable
FROM 
    sys.parameters AS parameter 
INNER JOIN 
    sys.procedures AS procedures ON parameter.object_id = procedures.object_id 
INNER JOIN 
    sys.types AS types ON parameter.system_type_id = types.system_type_id 
                       AND parameter.user_type_id = types.user_type_id
WHERE 
    procedures.name = 'UsernameSP'
```

This returns a result set:

```
name           name        is_nullable
--------------------------------------
@Username      nvarchar    1
@CreateDate    datetime    1
```

I need this query for an Oracle database. How can I run this query in Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select argument_name,position, data_type
from user_arguments
where object_name =  <your procedure>
order by position
```

That assumed you are logged in to the current schema where the procedure resides.  I don't think oracle has an equivalent of "is_nullable"